# How can the trigger function be written inside of an another function in pl/pgsql?

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers, plpgsql

I'm trying to write a trigger function inside a nested function:

```
create or replace function get_book(val1 varchar, val2 varchar default null, val3 varchar default null)
returns table(books varchar, its_category varchar)
language plpgsql

as 
$$
    declare 
    fav_book varchar(255) := val1;
    author_name varchar(255):= val2;
    category_name varchar(255) := val3;
    
begin 
    if fav_book in(select book_name from books) then 
    
          return query 
          select b.book_name, ca.category 
          from books as b inner join categories as ca on b.category_id = ca.category_id
          where ca.category= category_name;
          
          
    else 
        begin 
            create or update function trigger_insertion()
            returns void 
            language plpgsql
            as $$
                begin 
                    insert into books(book_name)
                    values(fav_book);
                    
                    create or update insert_category_author()
                    returns trigger 
                    language plpgsql
                    as $$
                        declare
                            cat_id int;
                            auth_id int;
                        begin 
                                if category_name in (select category from categories) then 
                                    select category_id into cat_id from categories where category_name = category
                                    update books
                                    set new.category_id = cat_id;

                                else 
                                    begin 
                                        insert into categories(category)
                                        values(category_name);
                                        select category_id into cat_id from categories where category_name = category;
                                        update books
                                        set new.category_id = cat_id;
                                    end;

                                end if;

                                if author_name in (select author from authors) then
                                    select author_id into auth_id from authors where author_name = author
                                    update books
                                    set new.author_id = auth_id;

                                else 
                                    begin 
                                        insert into authors(author)
                                        values(author_name);
                                        select author_id into auth_id from authors where author_name = author;
                                        update books
                                        set new.author_id = auth_id;    
                                    end;
                                end if;
                        end;
                        $$;
                        
                    create trigger update_books_table
                    after insert on books
                    for each row execute procedure insert_category_author();
                    
                end;
                return;
                $$;
                
        end;        
    end if;
end;

return;
$$;
```

I have three tables:
Books table which has category_id column referencing the category_id column from category table,
and author_id referencing the author_id column from author table, and book_name column.

Author table has author column stores book's authors.
Category table has category column which stores the book's categories.

What do I want to achieve is checking for the fav_book (a book given by the user) if it already exists in the book_name column in books table then show all the books belonged to the same category of the given book.
and if fav_book does not exist then insert that book and trigger the function (insert_category_author) this function checks for the category and author of the inserted book if both of them already exist in the tables (categories and authors) just it gets their id's put them into the variables and updates the books table's two columns (category_id, author_id). if they don't exist then insert them and do the update.

I just wanted to nest all the functions within a single one which is (get_book).
and I keep getting errors and I know a lot of things are off about the code but i couldn't find a way to implement my idea.

The error that I get is:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "insert"
LINE 27:       insert into books (book_name)
```

Comment: From performance perspective is very bad pattern to use any DDL operations inside triggers. This can be very slow under load of more parallel users (due locks). More - more triggers - slower execution. Stored procedures (triggers) should not be used by that way.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you have a few syntax errors and issues in your PL/pgSQL code. To achieve your goal of nesting functions and handling the insert and update logic for books, categories, and authors within a single function, you need to make some corrections. Below is the modified code:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_book(val1 varchar, val2 varchar DEFAULT NULL, val3 varchar DEFAULT NULL)
RETURNS TABLE(books varchar, its_category varchar)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
DECLARE
    fav_book varchar(255) := val1;
    author_name varchar(255) := val2;
    category_name varchar(255) := val3;
BEGIN
    -- Check if the favorite book exists in the books table
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM books WHERE book_name = fav_book) THEN
        -- If it exists, return the books in the same category
        RETURN QUERY
        SELECT b.book_name, ca.category
        FROM books AS b
        INNER JOIN categories AS ca ON b.category_id = ca.category_id
        WHERE b.book_name = fav_book;
    ELSE
        -- If it doesn't exist, insert the book and handle categories and authors
        INSERT INTO books (book_name)
        VALUES (fav_book)
        RETURNING book_name, its_category
        INTO books, its_category;

        -- Insert or update the category
        PERFORM insert_category_author(fav_book, category_name, author_name);

        RETURN NEXT;
    END IF;
END;
$$;

-- This function handles category and author insertion/updating
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_category_author(book_name varchar, category_name varchar, author_name varchar)
RETURNS void
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
DECLARE
    cat_id INT;
    auth_id INT;
BEGIN
    -- Insert or update category
    IF category_name IN (SELECT category FROM categories) THEN
        SELECT category_id INTO cat_id FROM categories WHERE category = category_name;
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO categories (category)
        VALUES (category_name)
        RETURNING category_id INTO cat_id;
    END IF;

    -- Insert or update author
    IF author_name IN (SELECT author FROM authors) THEN
        SELECT author_id INTO auth_id FROM authors WHERE author = author_name;
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO authors (author)
        VALUES (author_name)
        RETURNING author_id INTO auth_id;
    END IF;

    -- Update the books table with category_id and author_id
    UPDATE books
    SET category_id = cat_id, author_id = auth_id
    WHERE book_name = book_name;
END;
$$;
```

Here are some key changes and explanations:

1. I've combined the logic for checking whether the book exists, inserting the book, and handling categories and authors within the `get_book` function.
2. I've created a separate `insert_category_author` function to handle the insertion or updating of categories and authors. This function is called within the `get_book` function as needed.
3. The `RETURNING` clause is used to capture the inserted or updated values (e.g., book_name, its_category) and return them to the caller in the `get_book` function.
4. In the `insert_category_author` function, we first check if the category and author already exist in their respective tables. If they do, we retrieve their IDs; otherwise, we insert them and retrieve the new IDs.
5. Finally, we update the `books` table with the appropriate `category_id` and `author_id` based on the values obtained or inserted.

Please test this code in your PostgreSQL environment and adjust it further if needed to match your specific table structures and requirements.

Comment: Did you create this answer with [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1)?